# Autocomplete suggestions won't stay fixed

Tags: javascript, css, autocomplete, search-engine

I have a fixed banner at the top of my page with my Google search box in it. When I scroll down the page, the autocomplete suggestions scroll with the page.

How do I get the autocomplete suggestions to stay fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1947286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work -

```
table.gstl_50.gssb_c {
    position: fixed!important;
}
```